# Python - Bounding Box/Circle Library

Tags: python, gis, bounding-box

Python - Bounding Box/circle and string issues
I have a couple of issues I am trying to resolve in regards to some Python V2.7.x scripts I run under some Debian based units...

1) GIS - Bounding Box and Circles

I am trying to find a library that can do this

Given lat/long pair, point A determine if point A is WITHIN the bounding box of a lat/long set Point 1, Point 2, Point 3, Point 4.

Given lat/long pair, point A, lat/long point B and radius from point b in miles, determine if point A is WITHIN the bounding circle of Point B

Is there some library that does this?

The GeoPy lib I have to do the geocoding doesn't offer these choices. Some of the other libs seem to be related to ArcGIS shape files etc... which I am not using, and don't have any future need for them either.. certainly there is something that has some of this without the kitchen sink as well.

I've seen several things that take a Point A and give a bounding box...like:
https://github.com/jfein/PyGeoTools/blob/master/geolocation.py

Not what I am after... I want to pass Point a, with the box cords (P1-4) and it tells me if Point A is in that box.

Same for the circle. Point A, Point B and radius in MILES from Point B, and the function returns if Point A is WITHIN that bounding cirlce.

Anything that can do these???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It's a great place for some types of question, but not this type.  Please see [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

You may be better of asking your question at http://gis.stackexchange.com.
Anyway: checking whether a point is within a bounding box is dead easy: just check that both coordinates fall within the range of the bounding box. No need to use a library here. (check whether 
`lat_min < lat_oint <lat_max` and `lat_min<lat_point <lat_max`).

For checking the radius, you can use the vincenty function of geopy: just calculate the distance in miles between both points and check if the distance is smaller than your radius.

```
>>> from geopy.distance import vincenty
>>> newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
>>> cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
>>> print(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
538.3904451566326
```